# как сделать таймаут кнопки discord py

Tags: python, discord, button

код:

```
async def workbutton(ctx):
    user = ctx.member
    cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash + 150 WHERE id = {}".format(user.id))
    connection.commit()
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "workbutton")
    await interaction.respond(content = 'На ваш баланс зачислено 150 ')

код кнопки:

@bot.command()
async def workbutton(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Начинать зарабатывать', color = discord.Colour.random(), description = 'Для получение первых денег нажмите на кнопку ниже')
    emb.set_author(name = 'Информация', icon_url = bot.user.avatar_url)
    emb.set_footer(icon_url = bot.user.avatar_url, text = "Тех. Администратор Discord - Art")
    emb.set_thumbnail(url = 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/2d/32/2c/2d322c8ffb4f5bfc7bf7557a39f0b81b.jpg')
    await buttons.send(
        content=None,
        embed=emb,
        channel=ctx.channel.id,
        components=[
            ActionRow([
                Button(
                    style = ButtonType().Success,
                    label = "Заработать первые деньги",
                    custom_id = "workbutton",
                    
                )
            ])
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Хочу сделать так, что данную кнопку можно было использовать раз в час. При использование Timeout, не получается. Чтоб выдавала ошибку при использование через секунду.

Answer (score 0):

Слушай, можно просто сделать таймаут на команду:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
```

User можно заменить на member или guild.